# Solving QED Feynman diagram with one vertex

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering, feynman-diagrams

I'm new to Feynman diagrams and I want to calculate the probability of electron and positron anihilating into one photon to show it is impossible. I know this can be shown easier with special relativity I just want to improve my understanding of Feynman diagrams. I'm pretty sure I've made a mistake at some point in my calculations.

[image]

$$A=\bar{v}(p)\gamma_\mu eu(p)$$
Summing over spins
$$|A|^2=\sum\sum\bar{v}(p)\gamma_\mu e u(p)\left(\bar{v}(p)\gamma_\nu e u(p)\right)^+$$
$$|A|^2=\sum\sum\bar{v}(p)\gamma_\mu e u(p)\bar{u}(p)\gamma_\nu e v(p)$$
$$|A|^2=e^2\sum\sum\bar{v}(p)\gamma_\mu u(p)\bar{u}(p)\gamma_\nu v(p)$$
$$|A|^2=e^2\textrm{Tr}\left[(\hat{p}+m)\gamma_\mu(\hat{p}-m)\gamma_\nu\right]$$
$$|A|^2=e^2\left[\textrm{Tr}\left(\hat{p}\gamma_\mu\hat{p}\gamma_\nu\right)-\textrm{Tr}\left(\hat{p}\gamma_\mu m\gamma_\nu\right)+\textrm{Tr}\left(m\gamma_\mu\hat{p}\gamma_\nu\right)-\textrm{Tr}\left(m\gamma_\mu m\gamma_\nu\right)\right]$$
Second and third term drop out because of odd number of gamma matrices
$$|A|^2=e^2\left[\textrm{Tr}\left(\hat{p}\gamma_\mu\hat{p}\gamma_\nu\right)-\textrm{Tr}\left(m\gamma_\mu m\gamma_\nu\right)\right]$$
$$|A|^2=e^2\left[p^\alpha p^\beta\textrm{Tr}\left(\gamma_\alpha\gamma_\mu\gamma_\beta\gamma_\nu\right)-m^2\textrm{Tr}\left(\gamma_\mu\gamma_\nu\right)\right]$$
$$|A|^2=4e^2\left[p^\alpha p^\beta\left(g_{\alpha\mu}g_{\beta\nu}-g_{\alpha\beta}g_{\mu\nu}+g_{\alpha\nu}g_{\beta\mu}\right)-m^2g_{\alpha\beta}\right]$$
$$|A|^2=4e^2\left[p_\mu p_\nu-p^2g_{\mu\nu}+p_\mu p_\nu-m^2g_{\mu\nu}\right]$$
$$|A|^2=8e^2\left(p_\mu p_\nu-m^2g_{\mu\nu}\right)$$

Can you please point out where my mistakes are? I assume there's at least one since I expect the result to be zero.

Comment: It’s impossible because of kinematics. Such a process cannot conserve energy and momentum.

Comment: In more detail, what you've computed, $|A|^2$, is not itself a physical observable. You'd want to compute a cross section, which would involve integrating $|A|^2$ against the available phase space (a key word is "Lorentz-invariant phase space measure"). This measure factor is zero for your process since there is no way to conserve energy and momentum kinematicaly.